# removing partial html tags from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was going through the method of removing html tags from the content extracted from a website.

It might contain instances like complete html tags `<a href="\testlink"> tst</a>`

or broken ones like `<div class="testClass"`  or `class="testClass">` , Ive come up with a way of removing the complete tags, Can the partial tags be removed using javascript or jquery (regex way)???

The code that I used to remove complete tags are `replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')`

Comment: How would you know where the broken tag ends and content begins?

Comment: from what Ive understood the only thing that will help us find the end and start is < and >

Comment: broken tags are not tags they are simple texts.

Comment: yes.. but can they be identified and removed??? there is a method like ^.>
<.$ I think so..

Comment: That's what I'm asking. If you have `<option selected text`, how do you know if the word `selected` is part of the tag or not?

Comment: well if its a broken html tag, then everything comes after or before < , > respectively is included as part of the tag..

Comment: and if you have `<` in the text? You can't find if this `<` is part of broken tag or just part of your text.. @Rain is right.. broken tags are just text.

Comment: If you consider everything between `<` and `>` a tag, the regex you have should work.

Comment: what if I wanna remove all the the things occuring after < or before >

Comment: that would be crazy difficult to do imo.

Comment: it doesnt come in big paragraphs.. just a simple sentence... would that be difficult?

Comment: The thing is that we are humans. So we can know what is a broken tag. But getting that pragmatically in javascript is itself a big task. As this is a simple sentence, you can think of some set of broken tags which will come in the sentence and replace them with blank space manually by using string functions. But its too risky and there is high chance of side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to do using regex even with a high level language. But you could inject the html into the current DOM or for example in a hidden iframe. Then you build a "node walker" to go down the DOM-Tree and collect the "inner text" of the HTML-Nodes. As long as the DOM represents them you get what you want using the native DOM-Parser.

I did this once and it worked like this:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY');
function nodeWalker(node) {
 if(!node.hasChildNodes()) {
  return;
 }

 for(var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++) {
  // filter by node type == 3 equals TEXT_NODE
  if((node.childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) && node.childNodes[i].nodeValue.length > 0) {               
   // extract content in node.childNodes[i].nodeValue
  }
  // type == 1 equals ELEMENT_NODE
  else if(node.childNodes[ i ].nodeType == 1) {
   nodeWalker(node.childNodes[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp for all possible node types!

Another way is would ne to use AJAX and a server side DOM-Parser.